# Django Many to Many in template

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many

This is my template tag in a forloop

```
{{ product.feature_set.all.1.value }}
```

i want to change the number 1 to the forloop.counter. is this posible?

like:

```
{{
product.feature_set.all.forloop.counter.value
}}
```

It does not work like that, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: It has been some time since the question was asked. However, an answer can be provided if the `models` and `views` were included.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't make sense. You should be looping through the queryset itself.

```
{% for feature in product.feature_set.all %}
    {{ feature }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: no this is not what I want. I know you can do that. I want it like I asked. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 4):

Since @Daniel's answer doesn't satisfy you, I thought you might want to try writing a custom filter. Here is a rough draft:

```
@register.filter
def custom_m2m(queryset, forloop_counter):
    return queryset[forloop_counter].value
```

You can use it in your template like this:

```
{% for ... %}
    {{ product.feature_set.all|custom_m2m:forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the best and only way that I know how to do this.  The reason is that product.feature_set.all.forloop.counter is going to try product.feature_set.all.forloop and stop trying once it realizes that isn't possible.